# I was doing a python program to print only even length words in a given string, with the following code

Tags: python

## **PROGRAM 1**

```py
str = input('ENTER THE STRING:')
str1 = str.split()
print('EVEN LENGTH WORDS ARE:')
for i in str1:
    if len(i) % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
else:
    print('NONE')
```

## **PROGRAM 2**

```py
def linear_search(lst,key):
    for i in lst:
        if i == key:
            print ('element found at the position',lst.index(i))
            break
    else:
      print('element not found')
lst1 = input('enter the list').split()
print(lst1)
key1 = input('enter the key')
linear_search(lst1,key1)
```

In program 1, if I put a string not having even length words, the else part executes. But if I put a string having even length words the output shows both even length words and NONE (else part). In this case else part shouldn't execute right?

In program 2, if I put a key in the list, the output will be 'element found at the position...' without showing the else part. Also, if I put a key that is not in the list, the output will be 'element not found

My doubt is, in these two programs how is the 'else' part of 'for loop' working.

Comment: The `else` only executes if the `for` loop didn't `break`. It will always fire up in your first example because there is no `break` statement.

Comment: for loop didn't break means it will execute till the end right? then control go to else part...that's I understand...When for loop break the control will go out of the loop right? and why don't it go to else part...I can't really understand the difference

Comment: Because that's what `break` means: `break` the loop and skip `else`.

Comment: ohhh..kk..if there is a break statement in for loop it will skip the else part right? So in the first program there is no break statement and else part will execute in the both (even and odd length words) cases...now  i understand ...Thank you

Comment: Correct. That being said, both your implementations have issues: (1) will always print `NONE` and (2) will break after the first even length word. You should keep a count (or a flag) of even length words, then only print `NONE` if the count is 0 (or `False`).

Comment: Now I can correct my code ...Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is not in an indented format, I couldn't figure out if conditional "else" is for the conditional "if" or for conditional "for".

I would have extracted words as shown below.

```
>>> str = 'This is a random text for extracting the even sized words'
>>> list(filter(lambda x: len(x) % 2 ==0, str.split()))
['This', 'is', 'random', 'text', 'extracting', 'even']
>>>
```

For program 2 if your code looks like below, it works as expected

```
>>> str = 'This is a random text for extracting the even sized words'
>>> def linear_search(lst,key):
...     for i in lst:
...         if i == key:
...             print ('element found at the position',lst.index(i))
...             break
...     else:
...         print('element not found')
...
>>>
>>> lst = str.split()
>>> key = 'random'
>>>
>>> linear_search(lst, key)
element found at the position 3
>>>
>>> linear_search(lst, 'unknown')
element not found
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation at python.org - "[When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the sequence is empty or an iterator raises a StopIteration exception), the suite in the else clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)"

"[A break statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the else clause’s suite.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)"

Program 1 will print "None", execution of the 'else' clause, after the loop completes.

Program 2 avoids the 'else' clause due to the inclusion of the 'break' keyword.

Comment: Now it's clear ...thank you